# Use lock-free algorithm for shared memory

Tags: c++, ipc, shared-memory, lock-free

I want to use `lock-free algorithm` for shared memory for avoiding mutex. I have some processes that share data use shared memory. If a process is locking mutex and crashes, all other processes also crash.

I read some papers which implement lock-free algorithm with linked list. But in my shared memory, I can't define data structure for using on this block of memory. I have just a pointer to this block.

So I don't have any ideas for apply lock-free algorithm in my situation. I need some helps from you. Thanks and sorry if my English is very bad.

Comment: The standard lock-free data structures are FIFO and LIFO queues, implemented either as linked lists or ring buffers. You need to specify whether you want single-reader/single-writer, single-reader/multiple-writer, or multiple-reader/multiple-writer. The implementations get increasingly inefficient as you increase the concurrency demands.

Comment: I want mutilple-reader/multiple-writer and use ring buffer.

Comment: Not sure if a ring buffer is suitable for that scenario. Check out the queue by Fober, Orlarey and Letz, though ([part 1](http://www.grame.fr/Ressources/pub/LockFree.pdf), [part 2](http://www.grame.fr/Ressources/pub/TR-050523.pdf)).

Comment: But my problem is after creating shared memory, I will only have a pointer to this consecutive memory. So I cann't use any structures. I only organize somes area in this memory as a header to store read/write index, or head/tail,...

Comment: Perhaps you can make everything work with offsets relative to some globally constant base pointer?

Comment: When I have a pointer to shared memory, can I cast this pointer to pointer of my struct or class?

Comment: Only if the class is `trivially_copyable`, and if the pointer is properly aligned. This should be accompanied by placement-new-constructing the object in the shared memory in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

> If a process is locking mutex and crashes, all other processes also crash.

Specifically for this use case there are [robust mutexes](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_mutexattr_setrobust.html):

> PTHREAD_MUTEX_ROBUST
>
> If the process containing the owning thread of a robust mutex terminates while holding the mutex lock, the next thread that acquires the mutex shall be notified about the termination by the return value [EOWNERDEAD] from the locking function. If the owning thread of a robust mutex terminates while holding the mutex lock, the next thread that acquires the mutex may be notified about the termination by the return value [EOWNERDEAD]. The notified thread can then attempt to mark the state protected by the mutex as consistent again by a call to pthread_mutex_consistent(). After a subsequent successful call to pthread_mutex_unlock(), the mutex lock shall be released and can be used normally by other threads. If the mutex is unlocked without a call to pthread_mutex_consistent(), it shall be in a permanently unusable state and all attempts to lock the mutex shall fail with the error [ENOTRECOVERABLE]. The only permissible operation on such a mutex is pthread_mutex_destroy().

Comment: I known robust mutex in pthread. In multiple-processes, I used Boost library. But Boost has not supported robust mutex yet. I also read one way to use `pthread_mutex` in multlple-proecesses by set name for mutex, but the function set name is non portable. So this is not good solution. I am finding some helps for modifing boost library supporting robust mutex.